# how can I use focus function and calling a javascript function in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I call a function when press the textbox. this is the code for that

```
onclick="GetColorBack()"
```

but only when click on the textbox. but if I move with TAB it wont call GetColorBack function.

how can I do that?

PS: not the CSS focus type

Comment: Rather than putting the event on the item itself, your best bet is probably to add an event/listener to it.

Comment: Mmm, do you mean `onfocus` ?

Comment: @br3t please type that as an answer. thats the correct answer.
sucks to know that didnt made more reseearch before making this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "vanilla"-javascript use `onclick="GetColorBack()" onfocus="GetColorBack()"`

I think `onfocus="GetColorBack()"` will be enough, cause clicking lead to focus-event

Answer (score 0):

You can use [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) on the textbox.  This will work with clicks and tab overs.

Example:

```
$( "#btnTest" ).focus(function() {   
    //code 
});
```